# Why was Gendry picked to run back to Eastwatch?

Tags: game-of-thrones

This question was a JEER- in the column Cheers and Jeers in TV Guide 9/4-17/17 by Damian Holbrook-.

In the 6th episode of Season 7 of *Game of Thrones*, why was Gendry picked to run back to Eastwatch?

To me it makes a lot of sense. He was young, strong and uninjured. Holbrook thinks it was a bad choice because Gendry had "never seen snow in his life" but so what... it's harder to survive in the cold the longer you are out in it. I am right?

If there is a more knowledgeable official answer please post it. Thanks.

Comment: His prior Olympic rowing experience made him the most athletically qualified.

Comment: Also [Tormund really wanted the badass warhammer](https://youtu.be/q5NbZzseHPo?t=10).

Comment: Wrong episode, it was the Episode 6 "Beyond The Wall"

Answer (score 13):

He was chosen to run back because he was the fastest runner. Jon said so himself.

> "Run back to Eastwatch. Get a raven to Daenerys. Tell her what's happened" - Jon
>
> "No I'm not leaving you." - Gendry
>
> "You're the fastest. Go now!" - Jon

How we are suppose to evaluate this or how we would know without the explanation we don't know. But it is directly called out in the episode that him supposedly being a faster runner than everyone else is why he's picked to run back, which is a valid reason. We just have to accept this as fact and that was enough reason for the other characters to let him go.

Comment: You may want to add that in the end, he did end up being the correct choice as he made it, just in time.

Comment: “How we are suppose to evaluate this” — there is a chance that we’re not supposed to do an evaluation on every line that’s spoken in the show, and maybe just accept some of them instead.

Comment: Evaluation: Gendry is the youngest and has his body fully intact. All the others in the company are older and/or missing bits (internal or external).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That was what I was trying to mean. There's nothing to show it to be true besides what is told to us so we have to take it fact.

Answer (score 0):

The other guys have lived their lives and are settled with the prospect of imminent death. They recognise that gendry is still young, with many adventures ahead of him, and deserves the chance to have a life.

Comment: I somehow doubt the reason for him going was that they thought they were going to die. If that's the case they'd have all legged it.